# right to left localisation doesn't work on android

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I want my label to display from right to left. This code bellow works fine on iOS but not on droid. DO I have to set up something else on droid?

```
<Label x:Name="value"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"    FlowDirection="RightToLeft" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The app's **AndroidManifest.xml** file should be updated so that the `<uses-sdk>` node sets the `android:minSdkVersion` attribute to `17`, and the  node sets the `android:supportsRtl` attribute to `true`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" ... />
    <application ... android:supportsRtl="true">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The effect:

[image]

More info could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/right-to-left#android).